# Inherit from XCTestCase subclass

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, inheritance

How can you create the following structure:

```
CoreDataTests : XCTestCase

Entity1CoreDataTests : CoreDataTests
Entity2CoreDataTests : CoreDataTests
```

---

Explanation: I would like to write some tests related to core data (check), but I want to split them up into different test case classes, so in one test case class I would have tests related to the `User` entity, in another, the tests related to `Comment` entity. The catch here is that I'd like the two test case classes to share the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods implemented in CoreDataTests and just call them with `super` instead of having to copy-paste it around.

But since `CoreDataTests` is a test case class, it doesn't have a header file, so the `EntityTest` classes complain that they don't have a base class specified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just create a subclass of XCTestCase as you would a normal class, with .h and .m files.

So just File Menu > New File > New Cocoa Class with XCTestCase as the super class.

You can then create new tests using that as the super class, however, you'll still need to import the superclass .h file as it's not added automatically.

I did this for exactly the same reasons, testing core data and having common methods to setup up the context.

One annoying thing though, it still shows up in the tests GUI, just with no tests.

Comment: > One annoying thing though, it still shows up in the tests GUI, just with no tests.
So add tests to test helper functions in you core data superclass :)